# Does this sequence of polynomials have a limit?

Tags: limits, polynomials

Consider the sequence of polynomials $p_n$ defined as follows: $p_n$ is the unique polynomial of degree $2n+1$ satisfying

$$p_n(0) = 0$$
$$p_n(1) = 1$$
$$p_n^{(k)}(0) = p_n^{(k)}(1) = 0 \text{ for $k=1$ to $n$}$$

where $p_n^{(k)}$ is the $k$th derivative of $p_n$. For example,

$$p_0(x)=x$$
$$p_1(x)=-2 x^3+3 x^2$$
$$p_2(x)=6 x^5-15 x^4+10 x^3$$
$$p_3(x)=-20 x^7+70 x^6-84 x^5+35 x^4$$
$$p_4(x)=70 x^9-315 x^8+540 x^7-420 x^6+126 x^5$$
$$p_5(x)=-252 x^{11}+1386 x^{10}-3080 x^9+3465 x^8-1980 x^7+462 x^6$$

To give some intuition, here is an animated plot of $p_n$ for $n=0$ to $50$.

[image: Plot of p_n for n=0..50]

How can I determine, with proof, $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n(x)$ (if it exists)? I've never worked with functions implicitly defined in this way before, and I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: It seems that this sequence of polynomials converges pointwise, i.e., in the supremum norm to the function $f(x)$ which is $0$ for $0\leq x<\frac{1}{2}$, $1$ for $\frac{1}{2}<x\leq 1$ and $f(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @JankoBracic `pointwise, i.e. in the supremum norm` ? The two types of convergence are different.

Comment: @JankoBracic I suspect you're right, but how could one prove this?

Comment: Why? I thought it is the same.

Comment: @GPerez Can you explain, please, why thos two types of convergence are different?

Comment: @DavidZhang At this moment I have no idea how to prove it, however from the pictures which you show it seems that for any $x\in [0,1]$ the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}p_n(x)$ exists and it is as I said above. I think that this is a nice an nontrivial question.

Comment: @JankoBracic Pointwise convergence only assures $\lim_n f_n(x) =f(x)$ for each $x$, while supremum norm convergence assures that $\lim_n \sup_{x\in [a,b]} |f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$, which is a "stronger" convergence.

Comment: Perhaps you could study the solutions of the (linear) system of equations in the coeffients of $p_n$ $\{p^{(k)}_n(0)=0, p^{(k)}_n(1)=0\}_{1\leq k\leq n}$for small $n$, and work out a recurrence relation for these.

Comment: @JankoBracic : Suppose $f_n(x)=\left.\begin{cases} n & \text{if }0<x<1/n, \\ 0 & \text{if }1/n\le x<1. \end{cases}\right\}$  The $f_n(x)\to0$ pointwise in the interval $(0,1)$, but $f_n(x)\not\to0$ in the supremum norm, since the supremum norm goes to $\infty$.  Convergence in the supremum norm is the same as uniform convergence, not pointwise convergence. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: For a different point of view, what are the functions with $f(-1)=-1,f(1)=1$ and all other derivatives zero at that point?

Comment: @MichaelHardy THank you for the explanation. You are right. I was thinking about the closed interval $[0,1]$. I guess that on compact sets pointwise and uniform convergence is the same.

Comment: @GPerez Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Michael They look exactly how you'd think--affine transformations of the $p_n$. In particular, if you call your new polynomials $q_n$, then $q_n(x) = 2p_n((x+1)/2)-1$. For example, $$q_0(x)=x$$ $$q_1(x)=-\frac{x^3}{2}+\frac{3 x}{2}$$ $$q_2(x)=\frac{3 \
x^5}{8}-\frac{5 x^3}{4}+\frac{15 x}{8}$$ $$q_3(x)=-\frac{5 \
x^7}{16}+\frac{21 x^5}{16}-\frac{35 x^3}{16}+\frac{35 \
x}{16}$$ $$q_4(x)=\frac{35 x^9}{128}-\frac{45 x^7}{32}+\frac{189 \
x^5}{64}-\frac{105 x^3}{32}+\frac{315 x}{128}$$

Comment: The last row is $\frac{315}{128}(x-4x^3/3+6x^5/5-4x^7/7+1x^9/9)$, with the obvious Pascal coefficients. Does that help?

Comment: @JankoBracic, It's not quite true that pointwise convergence on a compact set is uniform convergence.  You need an additional assumption for this to be the case - for example, if you also assume that the sequence of functions is monotonic, then it's true (see [Dini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem)).

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thank you for your comment. I should know these things...

Comment: @JankoBracic : They're not the same on compact sets either. Just let $f_n(x)=\left.\begin{cases} n & \text{if }0< x<1/n, \\ 0 & \text{if }x=0\text{ or }1/n\le x\le1, \end{cases}\right\}$ and you have the same problem. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions which are $f(-1)=-1,f(1)=1$ and all other derivatives are zero are

$$C_n\int_0^x (1-t^2)^n dt$$

It follows that, pointwise, they reach constants as $n\to\infty$ because the bulk of $(1-t^2)^n$ narrows towards $x=0$.

The OP's functions are

$$D_n\int_0^x (t-t^2)^n \, dt$$

Let $I_n=\int_0^1(t-t^2)^n \, dt=1/D_n$.  Apply integration by parts, but let the integral of $1$ be $t-1/2$ instead of $t$, to use the symmetry between $0$ and $1$.

$$
\begin{align}
& I_n=\left.(t-1/2)(t-t^2)^n\vphantom{\frac11}\right|_0^1-\int_0^1(t-1/2)n(t-t^2)^{n-1}(1-2t) \, dt\\
= {} & 0-n\int_0^1(-2t^2+2t-1/2)(t-t^2)^{n-1}dt\\
= {} & -2nI_n+n/2I_{n-1}\\[6pt]
& (1+2n)I_n=(n/2)I_{n-1}\\[6pt]
& (2n+1)D_{n-1}=(n/2)D_n\\[6pt]
& (2n+1)(2n)D_{n-1}=n^2D_n
\end{align}
$$

Now David's formula for $D_n$ follows by induction.

Comment: Amazing observation! Do you think there is any hope of obtaining $C_n$ or $D_n$ in general? If it helps, it appears that $C_n$ grows as $\sqrt{n}$ and $D_n$ grows exponentially.

Comment: I conjecture $D_n = \frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^2}$ and $C_n = D_n / 4^n$, checked for $n = 1$ to $100$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the proof! The only question that remains open in my mind is how we might formalize the argument; that "the bulk of $(1-t^2)^n$ narrows towards $x=0$" seems rather hand-wavy. Is it possible, perhaps, to establish a rough bound on $|p_n(x) - u(x-1/2)|$ (where $u$ is the unit step function)?

Answer (score 0):

@Michael has already found a very elegant answer, but I would like to contribute an alternate approach that I stumbled across. It turns out that the polynomials $p_n$ are precisely the degree $2n+1$ Bernstein polynomial approximants of $u(x-1/2)$, where $u$ is the unit step function (and $u(0) = 1/2$). These are well-known to converge to the original function.